# Array initialization in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am just wondering what is the reason for so abundant for loop in the Array initialization.  For example this code:

```
count = (0 for [0..@size])
```

gives:

```
 return count = (function() {
   var _i, _ref, _results;
  _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _ref = this.size; 0 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; 0 <= _ref ? _i++ : _i--) {
      _results.push(0);
    }
    return _results;
  }).call(this);
```

Why Coffeescript uses so redundant code instead of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
   _results[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might look a redundant in single usage of that but generally it built in way to consider all possible scenarios and make generated code safer as it possible. I can see at least three issues solved by that code (not sure how correctly call these):

1. Variable name conflict
2. Variable scope conflict
3. Backward loop support (when size < 0)

You can read a bit [there](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope).